# External event to Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I need to create a dynamic page with a plugin called Fullcalendar.
I want to drag an event (div) to the calendar from a sidebar.
Any idea how to do this with Fullcalendar or with an other plugin? 
Any example?

I found this link http://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/tree/fcdraggable, but it doesn't work fine for me and it has some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running examples/external-event-drag.html and examples/external-event-drag2.html? they show you how to use it. what is buggy about them?

if you can't get them to work, i am sorry, i cannot provide support, b/c that code is not officially released.

good luck

Comment: Hi arshaw, Is it possible to get year by using plugin?